# Как сортировать по алфавиту ссылки

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Этим я отсортировал только текст, но ссылки остались на прежних местах. Как сделать чтобы текст ссылки соответствовал адресу ссылки после сортировки?

```js
var x = $('ul li').length;
var mas = [];
var mas2 = [];
$('ul li').each(function( index ) {
  mas[index] = $(this).text();
 mas2[index] = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
});
mas.sort();
$( 'ul li' ).each(function( index ) {
 $(this).find('a').text( mas[index]);
  $(this).find('a').attr( 'href', mas2[index] );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="h1">7</a></li>
  <li><a href="h2">6</a></li>
  <li><a href="h3">5</a></li>
  <li><a href="h4">4</a></li>
  <li><a href="h5">3</a></li>
  <li><a href="h6">2</a></li>
  <li><a href="h7">1</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: тебе нужно одновременно и тексты и ссылки? тогда текст со ссылкой не будет совпадать с начальной версии

Comment: Razmik Galstyan Да чтобы и текст и ссылки сортировались. Ссылку с текстом путать нельзя

Comment: Тебе так надо да?      
      <li><a href="h1">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="h2">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="h3">3</a></li>
      <li><a href="h4">4</a></li>
      <li><a href="h5">5</a></li>
  <li><a href="h6">6</a></li>
  <li><a href="h7">7</a></li>

Comment: @Razmik Galstyan Нет. Чтобы ссылка менялась местами вместе с текстом

Comment: Чтобы ссылка менялась местами вместе с текстом. Т. е. на данный момент текст и ссылка правильные. Но нужно сделать в алфавитном порядке. как-то двумерном массивом может

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У метода сортировки есть параметр — функция сравнения, возвращающая строку, по которой алгоритм будет сравнивать элементы массива. В этом массиве содержатся потомки выбранного `<ul>` — теги `<li>`. Вставка отсортированной последовательности обратно на страничку производится присвоением свойству **innerHTML** разметки, составляющей наши отсортированные элементы. Это, кажется, самый простой способ замены содержимого какого-либо тега.

Код оказалось проще написать без применения jQuery, поэтому без неё.

```js
var container = document.getElementById('cont');
var elements = [].slice.call(container.children);
elements.sort(el => el.textContent);
container.innerHTML = elements.map(el => el.outerHTML).join("");
```

```html
<ul id="cont">
  <li><a href="h1">7</a></li>
  <li><a href="h2">6</a></li>
  <li><a href="h3">5</a></li>
  <li><a href="h4">4</a></li>
  <li><a href="h5">3</a></li>
  <li><a href="h6">2</a></li>
  <li><a href="h7">1</a></li>
</ul>
```